# Webscraping page that require cookies with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the results of [this booking website](https://alilauro-tickets.certusonline.com/). The site drops a cookie to recognise the session. I've tried replicating it with `requests` but I still getting an `Invalid Session ID error` in my response. What am I doing wrong?

```
url = 'https://alilauro-tickets.certusonline.com/php/proxy.php'
s = requests.Session()
s.get(url)
data = {
    'msg': 'TimeTable',
    'req': '{"getAvailability":"Y","getBasicPrice":"Y","getRouteAnalysis":"Y","directOnly":"Y","legs":1,"pax":1,"origin":"BEV","destination":"FOR","tripRequest":[{"tripfrom":"BEV","tripto":"FOR","tripdate":"2020-03-21","tripleg":0}]}'
}
r = s.post(url, data=data, cookies=s.cookies)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
'sessionID': none, 'errorCode': '620', 'errorDescription': 'Invalid Session Number'
```

Here is the cookie information:
[Cookie informaiton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0n7x.png)

Comment: This website uses XHR. Without a JavaScript engine you can not render it. Requests does not have a JavaScript engine. Try using Selenium or a similar technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the cookie is present  when you call `https://alilauro-tickets.certusonline.com/php/proxy.php` but the cookie is not valid until a Javascript function call `https://alilauro-tickets.certusonline.com/php/proxy.php?msg=Connect`. This is a protection against CSRF as Dan-Dev mentionned it in comments.

Using the following would work :

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://alilauro-tickets.certusonline.com/php/proxy.php"

session = requests.Session()

r = session.post(url, data= { "msg": "Connect"})
r = session.post(url, data= { 
    "msg": "TimeTable", 
    "req": json.dumps({
        "getAvailability":"Y",
        "getBasicPrice":"Y",
        "getRouteAnalysis":"Y",
        "directOnly":"Y",
        "legs":"1",
        "pax":1,
        "origin":"FOR",
        "destination":"BEV",
        "tripRequest":[{
            "tripfrom":"FOR",
            "tripto":"BEV",
            "tripdate":"2020-03-20",
            "tripleg":0
        }]
    })
})

print(json.loads(r.text)["VWS_Trips_Trip"])
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bertrand Martel. I've learnt something new.